# import requests - doesn't work. pip install requests/pip3 install requests..done

Tags: python, import, python-requests

any help with import requests. 
I did

```
pip install requests 
pip3 install requests 
pip3 install lxml
```

etc
I think the issue may something with python paths...Anaconda broke it maybe..

```
-bash: /Users/matt/opt/anaconda3/bin:/Users/matt/anaconda3/condabin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Applications/VMware: No such file or directory
```

It seems like when running Anaconda it passes import requests line..but need this working in other tools...any ideas? thx for help

so I just tried directly from terminal and it also passed import requests line...stopping on 
import selenium..which is another issue...but why Pycharm can't go through import requests line...

Comment: have you tried `pip3 list` does that show your module there? And also are you using any virtual environment?

Comment: it shows there..it looks like anaconda is default path for python.and pycharm was pointing to default Mac path./Users/matt/opt/anaconda3/bin                                                    I added Pycharm interpreter path to that anaconda folder and now works..but now question how can I make default Mac OS path back as default ...I removed anaconda but paths are still there.